# Round number with arbitrary base, e.g.: base 7

Tags: r, rounding

Is there a built-in (or existing in any package) function that rounds numbers with arbitrary base? E.g. a la `round_base(26,base = 7)` gives `28`. Thanks!

Simple code:

```
n = 26.5
base = 7

a = round(n)
print(a)
for (i in round(a-base/2):round(a+base/2)) {
  if (i %% (base) == 0) a = i 
}

print(a)  

[1] 28
```

Comment: You mean, tranforming a number `n` into the nearest number of the form `kb`, given any `b`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `n` can be any number

Comment: P.S. I could certainly write such a function, but was just wondering if one exists already so I do not reinvent the wheel

Comment: I have never seen such a function, so I think you'll have to write it yourself. But that's not difficult.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's worth to add an extra dependency to your project, just to avoid writing ten lines of code.

Comment: it's not ten lines of code, it's one (if you squeeze a little bit)

Comment: @Ben Bolker, you're solution is much cleaner and shorter than what I had in mind. Very well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
round_base <- function(x,base) {
    round(x/base)*base
}
```

work for you?

```
round_base(26,7)
## [1] 28
```

Comment: Perfect! Very neat and a lot cleaner than mine